# Query parent relation when querying for child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, where-clause

Tech specs: ruby 2.1.5p273, Rails 4.2.3.

I need to pull a list of child records, based on it's own parameters and it's parent's parameters.

Child = **Video**

Parent = **Player**

The "date" attribute belongs to **Video**, the "org_id" belongs to **Player**.

I tried:

```
@videos = Video.where(date: start_date..end_date).includes(:player_page).
where(org_id: org_id)
```

but I get:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'videos.org_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `videos`...
```

basically, the second where clause is querying **Videos**, not **Players**.

To sum up: my intention is to query a set of Video records that fit within a date range and also match its parent's org_id. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@videos = Video.where(date: start_date..end_date).includes(:player_page).
where(player_page: { org_id: org_id })
```